Is it really interesting to prove well-posedness of unsolved SPDE?
Lots of nonlinear SPDE remained open for decades (especially the non-deterministic ones in higher dimensions because of the regularity of the noise) until Hairer's breakthrough (regularity structures), along with (higher order) para-controlled distributions allowing to prove, at least, local well posedness of the sub-critical equations.
For these equations, the following are common:

Lower dimensions are usually deterministic.
From a given dimension, we can usually apply Debussche-DaPrato trick or another ingenious decomposition to prove local well posedness, where renormalization, fixed point argument are only needed (no need for regularity structures...)
In higher determined dimensions, we are required to use regularity structures or (higher order) para-controlled distribution to obtain a fixed point argument, along the way we need to renormalize and construct the involved rough distributions.

Until now, at least, local well-posedness of many (sub-critical) equations (in higher dimensions) are still unproved (using regularity structures or para-controlled distribution to establish a fixed point argument, of course with the construction of the rough distributions).
Theoretically speaking, it's possible to prove local well posedness for sub-critical SPDE at least using regularity structures. From a research point of view, is it still really "interesting-valuable" to prove local well posedness of unsolved SPDE (using either technique and filling in details...) ?

Could you give an example of one of the subcritical equations that you have in mind for which regularity structures don’t already provide a small time solution theory?

@RhysSteele from your question, do I understand that they are all treated? (A paper, that doesn't do it for a "given equation", instead that deals with a large class of equations using regularity structures)

See e.g. metatheorem 2.18 in  the paper  "renormalising SPDEs in regularity structures" by Bruned, Chandra, Chevyrev and Hairer for a rough statement. Apart from some technical conditions, I would say local time solution theories for essentially all subcritical systems of parabolic semilinear SPDEs are already known.

@RhysSteele I guess there are still some non-local evolution equations that don't quite fit into the general framework, but of course the most interesting example in that class (Navier-Stokes) has been dealt with.

@MartinHairer RhysSteele, the examples, which actually are my (thesis) research that I am studying using both ways, are the stochastic Cahn-Hilliard (sub-critical for $d\leq 5$) and stochastic Kuramoto-Sivashinsky equations (sub-critical for $d\leq 7$), deterministic cases of these equations have only been studied-published (for Cahn-hilliard it's $d=1,2,3$, Kuramoto-sivashinsky $d=1$) so far, on the other hand $d=4$ for C-H or $d=2,3,4$ for KS where we use Debussche-DaPrato are not yet tackled, $d=5$ for C-H, $d\geq 5$ for KS requires regularity structures or para-controlled distrobutions

@mathex These are special cases of the general results Rhys mentioned. The reason why the statements of the results are fiddly is that there are several potential pitfalls that need to be detected by them. These include the possibility of variance blowup (see my paper with that title) and the possibility of solutions being below the well-posedness threshold for the deterministic equation.

@MartinHairer The uniqueness part is in Remark 2.22 after the local existence theorem from the paper: renormalising SPDEs in regularity structures (the theorem gives sufficient conditions for the existence only) doesn't hold in general, this leaves us the question of this post: is it really "crucial-interesting" to have a thorough study of local well-posedness of SPDE never tackled before? One possible outcome of local well-posedness is trying to prove global well-posedness (in space or time)

@mathex I think you misunderstood this remark: it says that you have uniqueness, modulo the choice of renormalisation procedure. This is an inherent property of these kinds of singular SPDEs and would apply equally to every single other solution theory we have.
